# Data binding Error:(421, 17) error: variable xyzViewHand is already defined in method _internalCallbackOnClick(int,View)

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

XyzFragment.java

```
public class XyzFragment extends Fragment implements XyzViewHandler {

    FragmentXyzBinding fragmentXyzbinding;
    XyzModel xyzModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        fragmentXyzbinding= DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_xyz, container, false);
        fragmentXyzbinding.setXyzViewHandler(this);
        xyzModel = new XyzModel();
        fragmentXyzbinding.setXyzModel(xyzModel);
        return fragmentXyzbinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

fragment_xyz.xml

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

            <data>

                <variable
                    name="xyzModel"
                    type="com.android.xyzModel" />

                <variable
                    name="xyzViewHandler"
                    type="com.android.XyzViewHandler" />
            </data>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/login_bg">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
           android:id="@+id/edtFirstName"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight_margin"
           android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDivider"
           android:hint="@string/first_name"
           android:inputType="textPersonName"
           android:text="@={xyzModel.firstName}"
           android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />

   <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="@{() -> xyzViewHandler.onRegisterClick(xyzModel)}"
          android:text="@string/register"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

XyzViewHandler.java

```
public interface XyzViewHandler{

    public void onRegisterClick(XyzModel xyzModel);
}
```

XyzModel.java

```
public class XyzModel {

    String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

This is my code for `two way data binding` with fragment same code working fine with `activity` but it is giving error if working with `fragment` when I write my  `fragment_xyz.xml` button click like -

```
<Button
          android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="@{XyzViewHandler.onRegisterClick}"
          android:text="@string/register"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
```

XyzViewHandler.java

```
public interface XyzViewHandler{

    public void onRegisterClick(View view);
}
```

it is working good with fragment also but when I add Lambda expression in xml file like code above it giving Error giving in the `FragmentXyzBinding.java` auto created class of `dataBinding`

```
    Error:(421, 17) error: variable xyzViewHand is already defined in method _internalCallbackOnClick(int,View)
    Error:(425, 55) error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to XyzViewHandler
    Error:(426, 13) error: incompatible types: XyzViewHandler cannot be converted to boolean
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

FragmentXyzBinding.java

```
// callback impls
    public final void _internalCallbackOnClick(int sourceId , android.view.View callbackArg_0) {
        // localize variables for thread safety
        // XyzViewHandler != null
        boolean xyzViewHa = false;
        // XyzModel
        com.android.XyzModel xyzModel = mXyzModel;
        // XyzViewHandler
        com.android.XyzViewHandler xyzViewHa = mXyzViewH;

        xyzViewHa = (xyzViewHa) != (null);
        if (xyzViewHa) {
            xyzViewHa.onRegisterClick(xyzModel);
        }
    }
```

Here It seems like `boolean xyzViewHa` and `ViewHandler refrense xyzViewHa` both are with same name so error occurs but same code working good with `Activity` and there I saw that boolean value generated like `xyzViewha0`

Comment: It looks like a bug in which the types and the variables are being confused. I should write a test for this. Try using camel case variables names instead of Pascal case. If that doesn't help, please post what is around the errors (lines 415-430) in the generated FragmentXyzBinding.java under the build/ directory.

Comment: Hello I edit my code with auto generated data binding code block where I get error.

Comment: `xyzViewHandler` is your declaration, but you use `android:onClick="@{XyzViewHandler.onRegisterClick}"` - is this just a typo (Notice the upper case `X`)?

Comment: Yes this is just typo mistake ignore this I am pretty sure that there is not any typo mistakes in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Debanjan says, change the name of the variable name to something else

**1)** In your layout file

```
<variable
    name="handleXy"
    type="com.android.XyzViewHandler" />
```

and

```
android:onClick="@{() -> handleXy.onRegisterClick(xyzModel)}"
```

**2)** In your java file

For example. for me, was databinding so I had to rename in a method like

```
_viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.handleXy, _callback);
```

(this is not your case, but might be useful for someone else)

**3)** Delete (or cut) the problematic method in the FragmentXyzBinding.java, and save it.

**4)** Rebuild.

That's the way I solve it and could rebuild my project again.
This is a terrible bug.

Answer (score 1):

@Pity I had the same error, and as you said the reason being "boolean xyzViewHa and ViewHandler refrense xyzViewHa both are with same name ",
So I changed the variable name to something arbitary in layout, like

```
<variable
     name="handleXy"
     type="com.android.XyzViewHandler" />
```

and there was a successful build. May be this is a bug in data binding library.